# To Depend on a Parameter or a reference type Property?

Tags: software-design

I have designed a class method as follows:

```
public MatchingSearchRecordsDto SearchForMatchingRecordsWithinAnOrganization(string matchText, int organizationId);
```

The class that this method belongs to has a Property reference to a large, complex GeneralObjectClass type, which itself contains details from the http request context including a UserID, from which I could query for the organizationId of the organization to which the calling user belongs, instead of asking a front-end developer to provide the extra organizationId parameter.

Basically, I wanted to know from a perspective simplifying code development and maintenance, which would be the preferred way to call the method, and why?

Thank you everyone for your answers.